# Exams (Conditional probability)

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A professor gives only two types of exams: easy and difficult. The probability of a difficult exam is 0.8. At the same time, if the exam is difficult, the first example is marked as challenging with a probability of 0.9, for an easy exam it is only 0.15.

a) What is the probability that the first question on your exam will be marked as challenging ?

b) If you find that the first question is marked challenging, what is the probability that you have a difficult exam?

My solution:

Probability of first question being challenging: 
$\mathbb{P}=\frac{0.15*0.9}{0.8*0.9+0.2*0.15}$

Probability of the second case:

$\mathbb{P}=\frac{0.8*0.9}{0.8*0.9+0.2*0.15}$

Is that a correct solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree to your solution of b). Let me define the events:

D: Difficult exam, $\overline D:$ Easy exam

C: First question is marked as challanging, $\overline C:$ First question is not marked as challanging

For a) you use the law of total probability:

$$P( C)=P(D\cap C)+P(\overline D\cap C),$$

where $P(D\cap C)=P(D)\cdot P(C|D)$ and $P(\overline D\cap C)=P(\overline D)\cdot P(C|\overline D)$

Can you proceed?

Comment: $P(C)=0.8*0.9+0.2*0.15$?

Comment: Your calculation is right. $\checkmark$

Comment: yes, sorry I edited it, so the answer for b) is correct but a) is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, your answer for b) was correct from the beginning. And now the answer for a) is correct as well.

Comment: so the answer for a) should be $\frac{9}{50}$ and for b)  $\frac{24}{25}$?

Comment: For a) the result is $0.8*0.9+0.2*0.15=0.75$

Comment: oh, yes okay, I understand.. thank a lot

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105679/discussion-between-daniel-and-callculus).